# Python Timer Class: Keeping Track of State?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that uses the Python [Timer class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=timer#threading.Timer). I was wondering about whether or not I have to manually keep track of the state of the Timer. Namely, I had the following questions:

1. What happens if `start()` is called on an already running Timer? Is this the same behavior as the Thread class (which is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=timer#threading.Thread.start))?
2. What happens if `cancel()` is called on a Timer that is not running?

For the above questions, is the behavior well defined in either case? I can't seem to find the specific details I'm looking for in the docs.

Comment: What happened when you tried those use cases?  That's where to start.  If you're uncertain about the results you got, *then* you'd have a good question to ask.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
Also note that off-site links are not acceptable.

Comment: Just because I got a certain behavior on my machine doesn't mean it's what the standard says should happen. Said behavior could be different on other machines and implementations. The links you are claiming are "not acceptable" are the official Python docs. How else should I reference the docs?

Comment: Sorry; that "off-site" links comment is, if anything, a reminder for later ... I've handled too many questions this week with off-site code.  My apologies.

Comment: In general, Stack Overflow doesn't handle future hypotheticals.  If it's not covered in the standards, give it a try -- but if it's not in the standard, then it's quite possible that the behaviour is undefined, and opinion (gasp!) we would give you would be half-useless.  If you need to know what it does on other systems, try it on other systems.

Comment: Which is why (gasp!) I'm asking on a forum full of experts and folks who might be well plugged into standards committees and the like. There may very well be a defined behavior here that's just not well documented, hence my question.

Comment: "gasp" is because asking opinion-based material is specifically off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Given partial documentation, "what does this do?" is something you can ask the computer with a few test cases.  "What *should* this do?" is an off-topic discussion.  If you have something else in mind, let's work on wording that might get to the point better, without making those experts tune out the quesation.

Comment: My question is not "What should this do?". I can answer "What does this do" on my machine, which isn't a great sampling of different environments. I specifically asked if there is well defined behavior in either case I mentioned, since there is ambiguity in the spec (at least my reading of it).

Comment: "I can't seem to find the specific details I'm looking for in the docs." The docs say right there that "Timer is a subclass of Thread and as such also functions as an example of creating custom threads." That already tells you that behaviours are the same unless explicitly otherwise indicated, so question 1 is answered. For question 2, if you think it's unclear, you should take that issue up with the PSF; they have issue trackers and mailing lists for this kind of thing.